# Set Global variable from Controller function

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am working on CI project where i am stuck somewhere. I try to set a global variable value from function and access this value from other function. Here is my code..

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {

    public $gData = "";

    public function userinfo() {
        //Here i fetch user infomration from database table 
        $userName = "userName";
        $this->gData = $userName;
    }

    public function getuserinfo() {
        echo $this->gData;
    }

}
```

`userinfo` is my actual page which opens in browser, and fetch data of user from user table. On my view i have button on click of button i am calling ajax which call the `getuserinfo` method of controller, it suppose to return the username which i set in `userinfo` method but `unfortunetly` it not working. Any will `plz` guide me where i am making mistake. (I am not allowed to use session)

Comment: Those two controller methods serve separate requests. The entire controller is being destroyed and re-created in-between, it won't retain anything you set on it. Neither should it, since what would happen if you had two simultaneous visitors?! You'll need to pass the value through the URL.

Answer (score -1):

**try this:** You have to set user name first in global variable:

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {

    public $gData = "";

    public function userinfo() {
        //Here i fetch user infomration from database table 
        $userName = "userName";
        $this->gData = $userName;
    }

    public function getuserinfo() {
       $this->userinfo();
        echo $this->gData;
    }

}
```

**OR you can use constructor:** I am not familiar with CI

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {

        public $gData = "";

         Public function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->userinfo();
      } 

        public function userinfo() {
            //Here i fetch user infomration from database table 
            $userName = "userName";
            $this->gData = $userName;
        }

        public function getuserinfo() {

            echo $this->gData;
        }

    }
```

**Edited Answer:**
Based on comment the solution can be like this if you don't want to use session :

**1.** Create a view using the Query of userinfo.

**2.** Create a model using that view and write your logic.
I think this may help you . It will not slow down your result.

Comment: actually userinfo contains fetch code. If i call userinfo() method from getuserinfo(), the fetch code will execute once again, which i dont want to do,because user table contains lot of data, which take time to execute.

Comment: fetch code has user table and lots of left joins. And every table contains the lots of data. So, thus i dont want to call fetch execution multiple time. I fetch data once, extract some data from result and want to use it in getuserinfo() method

Comment: Ok i wil try for same.

Answer (score -1):

You can define the variable in the constructor as Amitesh stated or you could change your `userinfo()` method to just return data so the `getuserinfo()` method can use it. For example:

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {

    public function userinfo() {
        //Here i fetch user infomration from database table 
        $userName = "userName";
        return $userName;
    }

    public function getuserinfo() {
        // get the data
        $username = $this->userinfo();
        echo $username;
    }

}
```

By calling `$this->userinfo()` you'll be running that method and the return value will be available to any function (within the same controller) who makes the call